# Hiding keypad in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using the following code as util file method to hide my keypad whenever i click a button.

```
public static void hideKeyPad(){
        Activity activity = MainActivity.getActivity();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
   }
```

But the keypad is coming all the time. Please correct me.

Comment: please add your layout xml

Comment: do you want to disable the android keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

try to use this code it work to me

```
 InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
               getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
 inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                  InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hideSoftInputFromWindow` method and as first parameter pass window token of your `EditText`.

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
               getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEdit.getWindowToken(), 0);
```